# How to use multiple shaders with LibGdx + SpriteBatch

Tags: libgdx, shaders, spritebatch

I'm programming a 2D game libgdx. I'm using a `SpriteBatch` of course to draw some `Sprites`. Now I wanted to use multiple `ShaderPrograms` with the `SpriteBatch`, but unfortunately you can set only one `ShaderProgram at a time. For example, I wanted to draw the whole scene with a specific color and wanted to add a parallax effect to some sprites by manipulating the texCoords in the shader. I know in native OpenGL you can just enable as much shaders as you want before your draw call. But it seems that in libgdx it is not possible.

Comment: Why don't you just combine the shaders?

Answer (score 4):

You can first render your scene to a texture with the first shader, then render the texture with the second shader. This will apply both shaders to your scene. You render to texture using a `FrameBuffer`.

```
SpriteBatch batch = new SpriteBatch();
FrameBuffer fbo = new FrameBuffer(Format.RGBA8888, width, height, hasDepth);
TextureRegion fboTexture = new TextureRegion(fbo.getColorBufferTexture());
fboTexture.flip(false, true); // Have to flip on Y axis

public void render(float delta) {
    // Draw scene to texture
    batch.setShader(shader1);
    fbo.begin();
    // If you're having issues with the drawing try doing glClear right after fbo.begin().
    batch.begin();
    // Draw here
    batch.end();
    fbo.end();

    // Draw scene to screen
    batch.setShader(shader2);
    batch.begin();
    // Draw here
    batch.end();
}
```

The much simpler way would be to just combine the two shaders into one shader, though.

Comment: +1 for the answer, however the last sentence may be dubious if you need to apply the second shader selectively for some sprites